# PHP cookie problem - www or without www

Tags: php, .htaccess, cookies

Why is it that if I create a cookie on www.example.com and check it on example.com, the cookie doesn't exist there? I am planning to just use `.htaccess` redirect non-www to a www domain. But how do I solve this?

Comment: You have to set the cookie domain explicitly. Or use something like https://github.com/delight-im/PHP-Cookie which handles the "www" vs "non-www" case automatically.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Browsers are the main culprit here, not PHP. They store by domain, and don't know that `www` is a special case; from their perspective, `www.mydomain.com` and `mydomain.com` are different strings, and therefore have different security policies. However, there is something you can do.

When setting the cookie, use `.mydomain.com` (with the leading dot). This will tell your user's browser make the cookie accessible to `mydomain.com` and all subdomains, including `www`. PHP's [setcookie](http://us.php.net/setcookie) has the argument `$domain`, but it's fifth on the list, so you may need to set `$expire` and `$path` to their default values in order to get at it.

```
setcookie('name', 'value', time()+3600, '/', '.mydomain.com');
```

For consistency, however, you may wish to consider rerouting all web traffic to a specific domain, i.e. send `mydomain.com` traffic to `www.mydomain.com`, or vice-versa. My vague knowledge of SEO (edit if incorrect) tells me that it's helpful so as not to have duplicate content, and it saves you all such authentication issues. Additionally, if you store assets on a subdomain, having cookies on there slows down traffic by having to transport it each time, so storing application cookies only on `www` earns you that speed boost.

[Here is a tutorial on how to accomplish such a redirect in Apache.](http://www.thesitewizard.com/apache/redirect-domain-www-subdomain.shtml)

Comment: You're close on the SEO stuff.  It doesn't matter if you pick to do it with or without the www; as long as you pick one and stick with it.

Comment: www.* is not a special case.  It's a convention, but it has no codified meaning in the http/cookie RFCs.  It'd be pretty absurd for browsers to magically give www special treatment.  Regardless, +1.

Comment: Yeeaah, it's not. But before you learn enough, a lot of the inner workings of the internet seem like magic, so I'm willing to take things gradually when explaining ;)

Comment: Old post, but thnks for confirming the problem being with the browser! In my case, I'm creating/updating the cookie with a javascript call, where there is no way to force the browser to ignore "www" as oppose to non-www. So for now I'm redirecting my page to non-www if a visitor arrives that way.  And @FrankFarmer, I can confirm that as of 2019, browsers will still create distinct cookies for either case. I agree it seems absurd, but as we've learned in the mysterious world of the "www", what WORKS is more important than what ames SENSE, even while hoping we someday learn the WHY of it. :-)

Answer (score 2):

```
setcookie("CookieName", "value", time()+3600, "/", ".mydomain.com");
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can set the cookie at example.com (really .example.com) and it will be sent if they go to www.example.com, but not vice versa. This standard security policy is to prevent users' private data from being sent to unintended servers.

Personally, I use virtualhosts in my apache2.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    RedirectMatch (.*) http://www.example.com$1
</VirtualHost>
```

... in this example, everyone trying to load e.g. http://example.com/index.html is redirected to http://www.example.com/index.html.

Answer (score -1):

because php translates www.mydomain.com differently from mydomain.com. If the domains are not 100% identical the cookie wont match.

And I'm sure the browser also looks for 100% match of the domain name before allowing servers to overwrite them.

Just use .htaccess to redirect. It's the only SURE way to tackle this in all browsers.

Comment: Prefixing the domain with a period fixes the problem. Exact match is not required.

Comment: "because php translates"... It has nothing to do with php and everything to do with the browsers.  Browsers don't send every cookie they have to the website. They only pick the one(s) that have matching domain names.