# Why are cookies only sent to http://www.example.com and NOT http://example.com?

Tags: php, cookies

I have a PHP login which sets 2 cookies once someone login. The problem is that if you login from http://www.example.com and you go to http://example.com, you will find yourself not logged in. I think that is because the browser only send the cookies to the first syntax.

It is only one domain, the difference is the `www.` before the domain name, so how to set cookies to the whole domain whatever there is `www.` or not?

```
<?php setcookie('username',$username,time()+3600); ?>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2345137/php-cookie-problem-www-or-without-www

Answer (score 8, accepted):

setcookie  (  string $name  [,  string $value  [,  int $expire = 0  [,  string $path  [,  string $domain)

Use $domain = '.site.com' instead of 'www.site.com'

Comment: Be aware that this will send the cookie to **all** your subdomains, which might not be desired behaviour.

Answer (score 6):

There's really no reason to use both www and non-www domains. Use a 301 redirect to send all to the one of your choice. I prefer non-www because it's shorter. Here's how to do the redirect with htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```