# Single-signon: Login to two site at once?

Tags: php, authentication, single-sign-on

I need to check if sure is logged in

1. user login to account.domain.com
2. system creates session for account.domain.com

   (at this point i want the user to also login to support.domain.com)

How does support.domain.com check if the user is logged into to account.domain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  session_set_cookie_params(0, "/", ".domain.com");
```

note that leading dot. This functions should be called BEFORE `session_start();`

Answer (score 0):

If you change your session cookie domain to `.domain.com`, then the same session will be accessible on both subdomains.

[Session wont work with www](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6838677/session-wont-work-with-www/6838719#6838719)