# URL redirect in php cause session error

Tags: php, url

There an url `https://www.example.com/rtu_s1/login/signupcomplete.php` and when I copy and past in the another tab and press enter  then url become `https://example.com/rtu_s1/login/signupcomplete.php` and the session is not set ....how to make the session set for both ?

Comment: Can we see some code for the both? And are they `www.demo.com` and `demo.com`?

Comment: url 1st in this i have set some session and send a mail to user but when user click the url than it redirect to 2nd url and create session problem

Comment: Did you understand the question? Is one with `www` and the other without?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Session cookie and www](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5312188/session-cookie-and-www)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose your server config separates demo.com and www.demo.com in different VHOSTS. Make sure you use only demo.com (in redirects and links) or www.demo.com, either... or reconfigure your server so www.demo.com to be on the same VHOST (alias).

Instead of two VHOSTS using one with alias. For apache2 site should be like:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName demo.com
    ServerAlias www.demo.com
    # ... other stuff below...
</VirtualHost>
```