# Another Cookie Error

Tags: php, cookies

I'm making another project and I'm using cookies to store some unimportant login information.

My problem is that if I go to "www.domain.com", the cookie can be accessed, however, if I go to "domain.com", the cookie cannot be accessed.

I'm writing my project in PHP so if anyone has the answer, or a solution to this problem that would be great.

Thanks,
Mark.

Comment: Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2345137/php-cookie-problem-www-or-without-www (possible dupe)

Comment: Not sure if it will really matter for you but just remember that the more stuff you store in a cookie, the more overhead each of your http requests will have. This includes requests for images, stylesheets and scripts if they are served from that domain and not a cookieless domain.. Just something to consider when serving up cookies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you set the cookie, set it as .domain.com.

```
ini_set('session.cookie_domain', '.site-name.com');
```

or

```
setcookie ("cookie_name", "", time() + 3600, "/", ".site-name.com", 1);
```