# PHP Session saves but cannot be loaded again?

Tags: php, linux, session

I dont know what to do, on my local LAMP stack and my other server's LAMP stack it work perfectly fine so I have no clue why it wouldn't on my main server. At the start, I thought that the sessions werent saving properly so I found out what folder they saved to, went to it and found an empty `sess_...` file and a small `sess_...` file that is 67B. I checked the big one and it contains the right information but the client is obviously for some reason getting the 0B one, does anyone know a fix for this?

I can provide code if necessary but I dont see how it would be.

I just tested it on Edge instead of Chrome and that somehow seems to work, I have absolutely no idea what is going on

Comment: How exactly are you determining that the client is getting the wrong session? The session management code in PHP is fairly well tested. It's more likely the problem is in your code than it is PHP confusing two session files.

Comment: Yeah , you're probably right I just dont know how it would be happening. Im not defining any new sessions anywhere or using anything other that `session_start` so I just dont get how this happens.

Comment: Nevermind, it apparently does work on my other linux server, which is really weird. I guess i mucked something up installing it.

Comment: Did you get an error when you did `print_r($_SESSION);`?

Comment: Did you try looking at the source code in Chrome?

Comment: No errors when printing $_SESSION, just an empty array. I checked the cookies on chrome with the Developer View and I can see that it is assigned the wrong SessionID for some odd reason

Comment: Could it be assigned the wrong cookie from your old code?

Comment: Delete your cookie and do a hard-refresh.

Comment: Ive used incognito mode and that doesnt work, same with the hard refresh.

Comment: Haha I found out why when browsing my cookies with chrome, the www version my site created a different cookie, so when I loaded my site with a www. it worked. Is there any way to make it so they both work the same?

Comment: I'm not sure. You could revise your question and someone else might know. Here is also a link that might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2345137/php-cookie-problem-www-or-without-www