# setcookie() in example.com, cookie not found in www.example.com

Tags: javascript, php, cookies

I loaded http://example.com containing:

```
<?php 
    setcookie("mycookie", "hello", time() + 3600 * 24 * 31);
```

Then writing `document.cookie` in the browser's Javascript console shows the cookie. It works. Then I close and reopen the browser and go to http://www.example.com. Then writing `document.cookie` in the Javascript console doesn't show any cookie.

**How to modify this PHP code to make the cookie shared between http://example.com and http://www.example.com?**

Comment: Instead, redirect **www.example.com** to **example.com**.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP cookie problem - www or without www](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2345137/php-cookie-problem-www-or-without-www)

Comment: @NiravMadariya this duplicate question is a bit unclear / has poor wording obfuscated with `.htaccess` which is non relevant. Maybe it would be a better idea to mark the other as duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please correct the code like this -

```
<?php 
    setcookie("mycookie", "hello", time() + 3600 * 24 * 31, "/", ".example.com");
?>
```

`This slash (/) might trigger both WWW and non WWW and also every page of the site`
It might work for `http://example.com/*` and also `http://www.example.com/*`
It might work.

Comment: Ok to check the cookie is set or not please use an **Extension  on Chrome** https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cookie-inspector/jgbbilmfbammlbbhmmgaagdkbkepnijn?hl=en 

Or You can use any addon like this to any good browser...

Comment: Good Luck to your project ! :)