# why are cookies for www.mysite.org different from mysite.org

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I'm thinking this must be a flaw in my HTACCESS file, but I need help and need to fix this quickly! I've just launched a new music page, and I now see that cookies set by the page visited by www.mysite.org/mypage.html are not the same as cookies written by javascript, when the visitor arrived from just mysite.org/mypage.html. I discovered this after inviting people (via link) to go to the latter, but then noticed GOOGLE was showing the WWW link. I was initially thrilled GOOGLE had picked it up already, but then after testing both ways I realized the cookie problem!

I don't think my HTACCESS file has been touched since I first started with this hosting company almost a decade back, and at that time all I did was set up a subdomain using the host company's CPANEL tool.

I'm posting 'example.org' to show you what RewriteCond is in my HTACCESS file...

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain\.example\.org$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.subdomain\.example\.org$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/example\.org\/subdomain\/" [R=301,L]
```

The above seems to deal exclusively with the subdomain I mentioned, which seems to work fine either way. But I don't see ANYTHING there about just ensuring that www.mydomain.org equates to mydomain.org

Normally I would just experiment, and I've found some examples below which MIGHT help. But right now I've really messed up not noticing this problem. Visitors are showing up, and I don't want to fix one thing at the expense of another! Can this be fixed with an HTACESS mod like the below?  I *THINK what I need to do is something like this IF I want mydomain.org redirected to www.example.org

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.example.org$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.org/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Of if I'd rather do the opposite, redirect all www's to the bare domain name...

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.org$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/example\.org\/" [R=301,L]
```

If I try these...

1. will it make the subdomain rewrite that already works fail
2. If these are good solutions, should I put one of them BEFORE or
   AFTER the subdomain re-write (I know it needs to be AFTER turning on the RewriteEngine on)
3. If one of the solutions I showed above is workable, is there a PROPER way, meaning is it better to redirect everyone to WWW or just the bare domain?

On that last point, I'm thinking WWW is better, but I've sent guests links to the bare domain method for years, an yet GOOGLE is listing my page as WWW. Both obviously work, so there must be some "fixup" going on somewhere even without the HTACCESS file, but I can't have a situation where visitors getting to the site one way or the other results in different cookies when the page's javascript writes it!

EDIT...

Two things... I've also seen the redirect of www.domain to domain described this simpler way, and have decided I'd rather go the "non www" way unless I really should not....

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.org$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ http://example.org/$1 [L,R=301]
```

BUT bottom line I have tried it, and it doesn't do anything at all! It does NOT interfere with the sub-domain rewrite (which I put AFTERWARD in the .HTACCESS file, and it does not interfere with any of my scripts, but it does not re-direct.

On the other hand, for now I've added this javascript to the HEAD section of the page, and it works fine...

```
if(window.location.href.indexOf("www.") >= 0) 
  {
  var loc = window.location.href;
  var newloc = loc.replace("www.",""); 
  window.location = newloc;
  }
```

This is a similar thing to what I'd done when GOOGLE was mis-listing some of my non secure pages as HTTPS (which wreaked havoc when a visitor would follow the link). So the above works, but it is a definite kludge, and I'd rather do it the way I THINK is the right way, which would be in the HTACCESS file. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT... in a comment below, I was asked how I create the cookie. I use a javascript function like the below, and usually set the time to a data far in the future...

```
function createCookie(cookieName,value, timeInSeconds)  {
        var expires ="";
        if (timeInSeconds) 
            { 
            var date = new Date();
            date.setTime(date.getTime()+timeInSeconds*1000);
            expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
            }
        document.cookie = cookieName+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
    }
```

EDIT... ... success on the .HTACCESS method

I still don't know why neither of the above HTACCESS re-direct methods I tried did not work. However, this one does...

```
RewriteEngine on

#redirect www.domain to domain This one works!!!
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

I'll keep the javascript method in my back pocket in case the problem appears again, should I move to a different hosting company as I plan to soon. As for the "why" the cookies are different, I've now seen that as absurd as it is, browsers will consider the cookies written on the www and non www version of your site as distinct and separate. I suspect this must be a point of confusion everywhere. Now that I think of it, i have had issues where I went directly to a major business website and could not log in, only to have a CS rep tell me to try again with "www" prepended to the site name. Since that worked, I guess I'm not alone in realizing this was a problem... I'm just late to the party!

Comment: I don't think your .htaccess is relevant at all. Instead, show us how you set these cookies. By the way, why do you have _any_ non-secure pages? There should be no need for that.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - I was just pointing out that if you visit "mysite.org" as opposed to "www.mysite.org" , the cookies set will be for the one your browser is point to, and so will be different. The HTACESS (or my javascript addition I showed) ensure this doesn't happen. The cookies are written via javascript. I've added the function i use for that to the post. Thanks!

Comment: But if the cookies are set properly, that won't happen. You're probably setting them on the wrong domain. We still don't have a [mcve] for your cookie-setting code though, so can't actually provide a solution (though it will look something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2345171/560648)). It's a solved problem; websites have operated on `mydomain.com` and `www.mydomain.com` in harmony for over twenty years; no .htaccess required.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Well first,, that link was helpful, because it confirs what I've seen, namely that "Browsers are the main culprit here, not PHP. They store by domain, and don't know that www is a special case; from their perspective, www.mydomain.com and mydomain.com are different strings,". That said, it seems my javasript (or hoped for HTACCESS) is on the right track (or at least solves the problem).

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit As for complete code, yes it is! Just Use the Createcookie() on a page with nothing else, use it to create a cookie named "cook" with a value "hello". Load the site  with and without www. You'll see two distinct cookies created if you look at your browser cookies. THAT is my problem. Picking with or without (in my case I picked without). and forcing the browser to reload if its not the one desired ensures a cookie written AFTER such redirect will always be the same domain. 

Still just not sure why my HTACESS approach isn't doing anything.

Comment: Re-examining my javascript call, it looks like I may have an error in the last line where the "document.cookie=" appears. Looks like I'm not actually appending the path. I don't know if it defaults or not, but I'll try correcting that, and will try both ways again.

Comment: EDIT... nope... correcting my javascript to append the root does not make a difference.

Comment: Specify the domain for your JS cookie as well. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie#Write_a_new_cookie: _“If a domain is specified, subdomains are always included.”_ – so set that to `example.org`, then you should have `www.example.org` covered as well.

Comment: ... which is exactly what the linked answer says.

Comment: Two comments back, note that I explained that this didn't help. I corrected my code to specifically specify "/" for the domain, which would be the root. As far as the browser is concerned, if the visitor landed on "www.example", than that *IS* the root, and there is no way to force it further back. hence the other linked post (along with others I've seen now) recommends simply forcing a redirect to the version preferred.  So that's what I'm doing, in the HTACCESS file AND in javascript as a backup. So the "WHY" (my original question) has been answered, and a solution found. Thanks.